# Finding $A$ if $(1,1,1),(1,0,-1),(1,-1,0)$ are eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having some trouble solving the following question:

Consider the matrix:

$$A = \left(\begin {matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{matrix} \right)$$

With $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb R$. If $(1,1,1),(1,0,-1),(1,-1,0)$ are eigenvectors of $A$, find the values of $a,b,c,d,e,f$.

I think I can find some conditions for all variables and get a system of 6 linear equations with 6 unknowns, but this seems too complicated. Is there an easier way of solving this?

Comment: Two questions. Since you have $6$ unknowns, how many equations do you expect you need to find them uniquely? How is linear system complicated when you have an algorithm that will always produce a solution?

Comment: I'm preparing for an exam and I'll have 1.10h for 14 questions, so I only have 5min for each. I can't solve systems with 6 equations that quickly @Ennar

Comment: There is no magic wand here, the problem is equivalent to solving $6\times 6$ linear system. The system is quite easy to solve, though. Multiplying $A$ and the second eigenvector will give you $(0, a-c, d-f)$, and the first coordinate implies the corresponding eigenvalue is $0$, so $a = c$ and $d = f$. The same goes for the last eigenvector. Definitely doable in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the three eigenvalues.  Multiply the top row of $A$ by each eigenvector.  The number you get is a multiple of the first entry in the eigenvector.  $(1,1,1)^T$ must have eigenvalue $\lambda = 3$, and likewise...aha!  The other two eigenvalues are both $0$! So the matrix has rank $1$.

Which means that the other rows are simply multiples of the first row, and you only have $2$ numbers to find.  In fact it is even easier, the answer is just $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Note that $(1,1,1)^T$ being an eigenvector tells you the row sums are constant, so all three rows must sum to $3$, which fills the gap to reaching the all one matrix!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Robert's answer, once you know the eigenvalues, you can use Diagonalization: $A=SDS^{-1}$, because $S$ and $D$ are known and $S^{-1}$ is the inverse. With a TI, this is a breeze (even manually doable because of so many zeros in $D$)

Answer (score 0):

The first eigenvector gives us
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1& 1 \\
a& b& c \\
d& e& f
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
3\\
a+b+c\\
d+e+f
\end{pmatrix}$$
Since $(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector, $(3,a+b+c,d+e+f) = \lambda_1(1,1,1)$, so $\lambda_1 = 3$ and $a+b+c = d+e+f = 3$.

The second eigenvector gives us
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1& 1 \\
a& b& c \\
d& e& f
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
a-c\\
d-f
\end{pmatrix}$$
Since $(1,0,-1)$ is an eigenvector, $(0,a-c,d-f) = \lambda_2(1,0,-1)$, so $\lambda_2 = 0$ and $a-c = d-f = 0$.

The third eigenvector gives us
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1& 1 \\
a& b& c \\
d& e& f
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
a-b\\
d-e
\end{pmatrix}$$
Since $(1,-1,0)$ is an eigenvector, $(0,a-b,d-e) = \lambda_3(1,-1,0)$, so $\lambda_3 = 0$ and $a-b = d-e = 0$.

All together we have $a=b=c$, $d=e=f$ and $a+b+c = d+e+f = 3$, which implies $a=b=c=d=e=f=1$.